# PHP Script for execute raster2pgsql command?

Tags: php, shell-exec

I want to run the raster2pgsql command using php,

So I tried to execute it using shell_exec() function, it hasn't work.
I even tried to execute it using exec() function. But no result.

How can I run this command in php?

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        include 'DBConnection.php';
        $nam=$_POST['name'];
        $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"/home/vineendra/Images/".$nam.".".$ext);
        $output=shell_exec('raster2pgsql -s 4236 -I -C -M /home/vineendra/Images/'.$nam.'.'.$ext. '-F  public.trail | psql -d test -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -w postgres');
        echo $output;
    }
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="test.php" method="post">
            Name:<input type="text" name="name"/>
            <input type="file" id="dem" name="image"/>
            <input type="submit" value="upload" name="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my code.

Comment: make sure and test if the shell command can be executed by a user running apache server (I assume it is not a cli script)

Comment: also in some linux distros (eg Centos) php commands like exec and shell_exec might be disabled by default

Comment: Apache server is running through same user login. I have checked the shell_exec and exec commands for generic commands like pwd, ls etc., those commands got executed.. how can i get a error message if that command is not executed? am not getting any errors..